need help to do a placement grid in godot
I'd like to make a citybuilder with a top down view with a defined map and a movable camera as well as a grid system with a way to place buildings, for the logic (money,...) I'm ready to do it myself, but for the camera and especially the grid creation, I have no idea where to start and no tuto can help me. I have no idea where to start and no tutorial can help me. Do you have any idea of simple and easy example code or a clear tutorial for a beginner to start this game?
I've watched a lot of youtube tutorials and tried to understand kennedy's citybuilder but it's not what I'm looking for.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
